# Solving a img height issue within available lightbox code

Tags: javascript, css, image, height, lightbox

I'm almost done my lightbox, seen here on JSbin:

https://jsbin.com/pijoge/edit?html,output

and would like help with one small issue. Basically, any portrait images*(see last image for example)* height goes past the screen or windows maximum height. I want to implement something that allows the height to become flexible, and adapt to the screen.

I haven't come across the issue with any landscape images yet, but basically just want the image to fit within the screen at all times.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I edited this down a bit, but it's still pretty wordy - can you edit to be as concise as possible? Your "TL/DR" may not be specific enough - go ahead and explain exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: I approved the edit but I'll see what I can do about cutting it down MUCH more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just added width: 100%; to all your images in the lightbox... however, a basic computer screen is a landscape. So of course a portrait image will overflow.

There is some solutions in CSS, however, I think you should use Javascript to deal with it.

Just get your image ratio, the lightbox container ratio ( here it's the viewport ratio ) and apply the css accordingly : if the img ratio is superior to the container ratio : img width : 100%, img height : auto;, else, the contrary !

Put this code in a function, and call this function every time you display an image in the lightbox ( so when you open it, and when you change the image. )

But ultimately, I would recommend you to use a lightbox plugin because your way of doing it right now doesn't look very good to me ( putting all the images directly in the lightbox ), you should load them one by one via Javascript.

Comment: The width was set temporarily to 100%. I'd played with it a bit but set it back to that, because I'd messed it up too many times.

I've always been overwhelmed by plugins, finding step by step JS tutorials and coding it in by hand easier. But I'll try and find something plugin based that is simple.
Im not that informed in javascript so Im not sure how to write that function but I can try to look into it.